# Determine the expressions of base change

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

If I have the bases $\mathcal{B}_1$, $\mathcal{B}_2$, $\mathcal{B}_3$ y $\mathcal{B}_4$ of a vector space V . Known base change matrices $A = M(\mathcal{B}_1, \mathcal{B}_3)$, $B = M(\mathcal{B}_2, \mathcal{B}_3)$ y $C = M(\mathcal{B}_2, \mathcal{B}_4)$, determines what is the expression of the following base change matrices:

1. from $\mathcal{B}_2$ to $\mathcal{B}_1$.
2. from $\mathcal{B}_1$ to $\mathcal{B}_4$.
3. from $\mathcal{B}_3$ to $\mathcal{B}_4$.

> Someone can help/advise me with any of the sections to be able to move
>   forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading $B = M(\mathcal{B}_2, \mathcal{B}_3)$ as $B$ is the matrix that takes a vector represented according to $\mathcal{B}_2$ and represents it according to $\mathcal{B}_3$ to go the other way you invert $B$, so $B^{-1}=M(\mathcal{B}_3, \mathcal{B}_2)$.  Now to go from $\mathcal{B}_2$ to $\mathcal{B}_1$ you can go from $\mathcal{B}_2$ to $\mathcal{B}_3$ and then from $\mathcal{B}_3$ to $\mathcal{B}_1$ by multiplying matrices.

Comment: So i can say that $M(\mathcal{B}_2,\mathcal{B}_1) = B \cdot A^{-1}$?? @Ross Millikan

Comment: If your vectors are columns it needs to be the other order because you premultiply by these matrices.  You multiply the $\mathcal B_2$ representation by $B$ to get to $\mathcal B_3$, then multiply that by $A^{-1}$, so it is $A^{-1}B$ times the original vector.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to determine a base change matrix, for example from $B_2$ to $B_1$, you have to find the coordinates of each vector of the base $B_2$ in the base $B_1$, i.e., if $B_2 = {v_1,v_2,...}$ and $B_1={w_1,w_2,...,w_n}$ you have to find the numbers $a_{ij}$ such that

$v_1 = a_{11} w_1 + a_{12}w_2+...+a_{1n} w_n$

$v_2 = a_{21}w_1 + ... + a_{2n}w_n$

...
$v_n = a_{n1}w_1 + ... + a_{nn}w_n$

Then the matrix we want is formed by the coordinates of the vector, $a_{ij}$ is exactly the element of line $i$ column $j$ of the matrix we wanted to find.